# SQL get values for only a few hours in given time period?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My first question here..!

I'm not an expert in SQL, so bear over with me please! :)

I have a web page (not created by me) which gets report data from a MSSQL database, on the web page you enter start date and end date and data are fetched in this time interval from 00:00 on start date until 23:59 on end date.

I have managed to add more queries to the SQL, but now I would like to, for certain values only to return values which were logged in the time range 00:00:00 until 04:00:00 every day in the selected time interval.

Currently values are logged once an hour, but not always consistently. So far I have made a workaround in my web page which shows the first 4 values and skips the next 20, this loops for the selected interval. This method works 98% of the time, but occasionally there are more or fewer than 24 logged values per day which can cause the shown values will be skewed one way or another.

What I would like to do is change my SQL query so that it only returns values in the time range I want (between midnight and 04:00) for every day in the selected period. I hope someone can help me achieve this or give me some hints! :)

This is the existing SQL query running with the variables which I do want all values for. There are more variables than this but I edited them out, all the Ren*Time variables is the ones I want to make a 4-hour-every-day version of.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpValues') IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE #tmpValues END;

CREATE TABLE #tmpValues(Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),BatchId INT, TimePoint DATETIME, Ren1Time DECIMAL(10,2), Ren2Time DECIMAL(10,2), Ren3Time DECIMAL(10,2), RenTotTime DECIMAL(10,2));

INSERT INTO #tmpValues(BatchId)
    SELECT BatchId          
    FROM Batch
    WHERE Batch.LogTime BETWEEN <StartTime> AND <StopTime>;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX I_BatcId ON #tmpValues(BatchId);

UPDATE #tmpValues SET 
TimePoint = (SELECT LogTime FROM Batch WHERE Batch.BatchId = #tmpValues.BatchId),
Ren1Time = (SELECT SUM(_Float) FROM LogData WHERE LogData.BatchId = #tmpValues.BatchId AND LogData.TagId = 21),
Ren2Time = (SELECT SUM(_Float) FROM LogData WHERE LogData.BatchId = #tmpValues.BatchId AND LogData.TagId = 25),
Ren3Time = (SELECT SUM(_Float) FROM LogData WHERE LogData.BatchId = #tmpValues.BatchId AND LogData.TagId = 29),
RenTotTime = (SELECT SUM(_Float) FROM LogData WHERE LogData.BatchId = #tmpValues.BatchId AND (LogData.TagId = 25 OR LogData.TagId = 29 OR LogData.TagId = 33));

DECLARE 
@TimePoint DATETIME,
@Ren1Time FLOAT,
@Ren2Time FLOAT,
@Ren3Time FLOAT,
@RenTotTime FLOAT;

INSERT INTO #tmpValues(TimePoint, Ren1Time, Ren2Time, Ren3Time, RenTotTime)
    VALUES(@TimePoint, @Ren1Time, @Ren2Time,@Ren3Time, @RenTotTime);        
SET NOCOUNT OFF; 

SELECT * FROM #tmpValues; 
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpValues') IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE #tmpValues END;
```

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (That code is not ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: The use of `OBJECT_ID` signifies MS SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mess around with temp tables and processing every column separately. I also have no idea what you're trying to do with those variables. You declare them, never set them, then do an `INSERT` with them, which will just insert a row of `NULL` values.

Assuming that you're using SQL Server, the `DATEPART` function will let you get the hour of the day.

```
SELECT
    B.BatchID,
    B.LogTime AS TimePoint,
    SUM(CASE WHEN B.TagId = 21 THEN _Float ELSE 0 END) AS Ren1Time,
    SUM(CASE WHEN B.TagId = 25 THEN _Float ELSE 0 END) AS Ren2Time,
    SUM(CASE WHEN B.TagId = 29 THEN _Float ELSE 0 END) AS Ren3Time,
    SUM(CASE WHEN B.TagId IN (21, 25, 29) THEN _Float ELSE 0 END) AS RenTotTime
FROM
    dbo.Batch B
INNER JOIN LogData LD ON LD.BatchId = B.BatchId
WHERE
    B.LogTime BETWEEN <StartTime> AND <StopTime> AND
    DATEPART(HOUR, B.LogTime) BETWEEN 0 AND 4
GROUP BY
    B.BatchID,
    B.TimePoint
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your swift reply!

I couldn't exactly get your suggestion to work, but I did solve my problem thanks to your suggestion!

Since the SQL query which should be limited to the 4 hours is used only from one webpage and there are no values in this web page which should be shown for all 24 hours, I thought I could copy the existing .SQL file to a new file and simply change the following:

```
WHERE Batch.LogTime BETWEEN <StartTime> AND <StopTime>;
```

To

```
WHERE Batch.LogTime BETWEEN <StartTime> AND <StopTime> AND DATEPART(HOUR, Batch.LogTime) BETWEEN 0 AND 3;
```

I changed the call to the .SQL file in the web page from the old to the new file and it works! Simple as that! Also changed 0 AND 4 to 0 AND 3 since I found 03:59:59 will be included, which is exactly what I want :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! "Follow-up" information like this is best posted as a comment to the reply it applies to; done as a second answer can be confusing, since answers are not always listed in the order they were posted. Also, don't forget to "Accept" the most useful answer (@Tom H's) to your original question.